# How create and use two or more ViewData.Model 's

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

Can you help me how to create my own ViewData.Model from mesto?

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
            ViewData["Message"] = "Moji Priatelia";
            var friends = from friend in friendsDb.FriendsTables
                          orderby friend.Priezvisko
                          select friend;
            var mesto = from mesta in friendsDb.MestoTables
                        orderby mesta.Mesto
                        select mesta;

            return View(friends);
}
```

when i add new view ViewData.Model have data from friends but no from mesto how can i create model for mesto?
Thanks a lot i am Beginner.

---

Here i have problem.

```
public class IndexViewModel 
    {
        public IEnumerable<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Mesta> Mesto { get; set; }
    }
```

The type or namespace name 'Friend' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'Mesta' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But table have names FriendTable, MestoTable if i use this names it is corect. Then i do new View via IndexViewModel but i can't 
use this

```
<%: Model.Friends %>
<%: Model.Mesto %>
```

this stops with error 
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MVCApp.Controllers.IndexViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MVCApp.Controllers.IndexViewModel]'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a ViewModel and pass it to your View:

```
public class IndexViewModel 
{
   public IEnumerable<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Mesta> Mesto { get; set; }
}
```

For that to work, you first need to adjust your action method with something like that:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        ViewData["Message"] = "Moji Priatelia";
        var friends = from friend in friendsDb.FriendsTables
                      orderby friend.Priezvisko
                      select friend;
        var mesto = from mesta in friendsDb.MestoTables
                    orderby mesta.Mesto
                    select mesta;

        var ViewModel = new IndexViewModel {
            Friends = friends,
            Mesto = mesto
        }

        return View(ViewModel);
}
```

Your View now needs to be strongly typed with the `IndexViewModel` type.

Accessing your members would look somewhat like that:

```
<%: Model.Friends %>
<%: Model.Mesto %>
```

`ViewModels` are the way to go when you need to show complex data in your views that doesn't really project the domain model.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to wrap your two objects in another object and pass that to your view.

Such as:

```
public class FriendsMestoDataContext()
{
    public IEnumerable<Friends> friends{get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<Mesto> mesto{get;set}
}
```

You can then pass this new object to your view and access both the friends and mesto properties which will be the two classes you're returning from your Linq queries:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
            ViewData["Message"] = "Moji Priatelia";
            var friendsData = from friend in friendsDb.FriendsTables
                          orderby friend.Priezvisko
                          select friend;
            var mestoData = from mesta in friendsDb.MestoTables
                        orderby mesta.Mesto
                        select mesta;
            var dataModel = new FriendsMestoDataContext(){
                                            friends = friendsData,
                                            mesto = mestoData}


            return View(dataModel);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As Shaharyar said below, you'll want to strongly type your view with the `FriendsMestoDataContex`.